# HTML centered div scrolling + menu

Tags: html, css

I am new to website design and need help in centering a div that has 100% page height but 70% width, the width can be set and centered but the height is only as heigh as the content itself. For example like http://www.thelounge.fi/ however the scrolling part of this is on the left side while I would like it in the centre.

Thank You.

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: here is what i have done so far https://jsfiddle.net/7qna93tv/

Answer (score 0):

okey. In this case we have two solutions:

1. You can set the div `display` property  to `inline` or `inline-block`. And then set the `text-align` property to `center` for the div parent, as you could see here https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/7q9Lp45q/
2. Or you can give a margin to the child, if it has acertain `width` and the `display` property set to `block`, which is the default, like here https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/wwu5ttxt/

#### Further explanation:

In the first solution, you change the div default value for the `display`property. When you set `display`to inline you are creating a line element, which does not take all the space to its side. Then you change the `tex-align` property for the parent, that means that all childs that are line elments will be centered.

For the second one, we use the `block` value for `display`. Using this, the element, in our case, the div, is taking all the width available. For that reason, we need to set a width, for instance 25%. Now, the div takes only the 25% of the parent. The last step is adding a margin, which is the distance to the parent's bounds. In the fiddle we set `margin: 0 auto` which means that div will have 0 for margin top and bottom, and will take an auto margin for each side.

A good reference: [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to set content of hello div in separate div with overflow scroll, and you want to keep your HTML as it is you can margin-top to hello with same hieght of navbar and set navbar left (100-70)/2=15

```css
  body {
        /*background-color: #f0f0f2;*/
  background-color:green;
  background-attachment:fixed;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow-y:scroll;

    }

 
 .hello { 
  
  width:70%;
  background-color:white;
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
  background-position:center;
  /*margin-top:60px;*/
  margin-bottom:20px;
  height:100%;
        margin-top:60px;

 }
 
 .navbar {
  
  align:center;
  background-color:gray;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  height:40px;
  padding-top:20px;  
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255,1);
  position:fixed;
  width:70%;
  top:0;
        left:15%;
 }
 
 .navbar2 {
  
  align:center;
  background-color:gray;
  height:20px;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
 }
```

```html
<body>
 
<div class="hello">
 <div class="navbar">NAVAGATION BAR
 </div>

<p>test1</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test3</p>
    <p>test4</p>
    <p>test5</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
<p>test</p>

<p>test</p><p>test</p>
<p>test</p><p>test</p>
<p>test</p><p>test</p>
<p>test</p>

 <div class="navbar2">Bottom Bar
 </div> 

</div>

</body>
```